# CSS - MaterialUI - How can I make a table always take the full width, and not need horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have tried to set each widthPercent on each TableHeader to add up to 100%, but the scroll bar is still there.

I can set static widths per column, but I end up with extra space on the right depending on the size of the window.

How do I make the table always use the full width available to it, but also always wrap text so the table does not need horizontal scroll?

Comment: Add code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

MuiTable css override:
`tableLayout: "fixed"`

MuiTableCell css override:
`overflow: "hidden", textOverflow: "ellipsis"`